How do I render my data as I push my data in Vue
I am practicing Vue and created a todo ,but I am not able to render my text as I add it in my Input filed
here is my code

<template>
  <div class="App">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Todo App</h1>
      <div class="top">
        <input
          type="text"
          v-model="state.newTodoText"
          placeholder="Add a new task"
        />
        <div class="add" @click="addTodo">Add</div>
      </div>
      <div class="list">
        <Todo
          v-for="(item, index) in state.toDo"
          :text="item.text"
          :key="index"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { reactive, onMounted, watchEffect, provide, inject } from "vue";
import Todo from "./components/ToDo.vue";
import { getAllToDo, addToDo } from "./utils/HandleApi";

// Provide and inject state
const StateSymbol = Symbol("state");
const state = reactive({
  toDo: [] as { text: string }[],
  newTodoText: "",
});
provide(StateSymbol, state);

const addTodo = () => {
  if (state.newTodoText.trim() !== "") {
    addToDo(state.newTodoText);
    state.newTodoText = "";
  }
};

watchEffect(() => {
  state.toDo.forEach((todo: any) => {
    console.log(todo.text);
  });
});

onMounted(async () => {
  try {
    const todos = await getAllToDo();
    state.toDo = JSON.parse(todos);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching todos:", error);
  }
});
</script>

<style scoped>
.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  background: pink;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}
.top {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  justify-content: center;
}
input {
  padding: 0.5rem;
  width: 70%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.add {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.todo {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  background-color: #132743;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.icons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
}
.icon {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
</style>


This is my HandleApi.ts
import axios from "axios-typescript";

const baseUrl = "http://localhost:5000";

export const getAllToDo = async () => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get(baseUrl);
    console.log("Type of data received:", typeof data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching todos:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};
export const addToDo = (text: string) => {
    console.log("Adding todo:", text);
  axios
    .post(`${baseUrl}/save`, { text })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      getAllToDo();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};


How do I update myaddTodo after I push my data ,
data is not updated but as I refresh my page it is visible
I have tried adding a state to my addTodo but it is undefined

odd, you do nothing with the result of the axios post, and nowhere in your code is there any "push" being made to add to the todo's you have in state.toDo ... are you sure you've posted the correct code?

The getAllToDo does the fetching but updating the state.toDo gets done in your onMounted hook. So, in the addToDo function you need to take the same approach. By the way, why don't you update the to-do list in the fetching function?
